# errores similares a "GET /inicio/static/js/main.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3705

Tags: python, django, app

Estoy haciendo una app en django

Pero me esta dando un error en cuando intento ingresar con el usuario, que tengo registrado en una base de datos PostgreSQL, el formulario de registro funciona bien pero cuando intento ingresar me salta ese error en la consola y en la Web solo se limpia las casillas y no ocurre más nada:

```
[28/Jun/2023 18:40:29] Not Found: /inicio/static/js/main.js
"

GET /inicio/static/js/jquery.form.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3726
[28/Jun/2023 18:40:29] "GET /inicio/static/js/jquery.validate.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3750
[28/Jun/2023 18:40:29] "GET /inicio/static/js/mail-script.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3726
[28/Jun/2023 18:40:29] "GET /inicio/static/js/main.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3705
```

Gracias a quien pueda ayudar, he probado colocando el formato django en los enlaces, quitádolos, colocando en el setting `/static/` con los dos slash y sin ellos o con solo uno, ya me estoy quedando sin ideas.